# Does groupbykey functionality in Beam

Tags: apache-beam

We need to use groupbykey to achive the functionality

KV < ID , < List of objects > > like

KV <1, < obj1,obj2 >>

Could you please tell if groupbykey works in Spark runner. According to capability matrix it is not supported but according the following link it is supported.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-799

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press "expand details" on the capability matrix, you can see that GroupByKey is supported in the Spark runner with the note:

> Partially: fully supported in batch mode
>
> Using Spark's `groupByKey`. GroupByKey with multiple trigger firings in streaming mode is a work in progress.

Comment: The expand details Button doesn't look like a link. Me and my colleague got blindfolded and concluded that groupbykey is not supported in Spark.

Comment: Agreed, I've definitely seen better-looking buttons. The web site, like Beam itself, is open source and open to contributions, I think this widget is in https://github.com/apache/beam-site/blob/asf-site/src/_includes/capability-matrix.md and nearby css files.